# WPF-MVVM SelectAll property not found on object of type CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using WPF - MVVM and I've made a data grid that has a check box header, to select and unselect all [image]

but the view does not recognize
and here is the view code :

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" IsReadOnly="False" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox Name="SelectAll"  Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding SelectAll,Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckedRowFlag"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="125"  FontFamily="Tahoma" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modification Date" Binding="{Binding Modification_Date}" Width="125"  FontFamily="Tahoma" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding AreaID}" Width="125"  FontFamily="Tahoma" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area Id" Binding="{Binding Dataareaid}" Width="125"  FontFamily="Tahoma" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and View model code:

```
public bool SelectAll
    {
        get { return _selectAll; }
        set {
            _selectAll = value;
            foreach (var item in DataGrid)
            {
                item.IsCheckedRow = true;
            }
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DataGrid);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectAll);
        }
    }
```

and when I run the program this is what appears:

[image]

where is my problem and how can i make the binding works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `DataGridTemplateColumn.Header` element is not a part of the visual or logical tree.

Try

```
<CheckBox Name="SelectAll"  Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.SelectAll,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid},Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```